# Como mostrar resultado via ajax e jquery sem que aconteça refresh na página

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Tentei implementar uma chamada Ajax em um projeto e não consigo identificar o erro. Tenho um formulário para postagem de status e gostaria que assim que eu postar algo ele não dê refresh na página e sim que mostre o resultado, em seguida em uma div.

Acontece que ele está redirecionado a página e vai para / update_post.php
quando volto para a dashboard o resultado está na div de **Status**. e aparece na div de baixo. Tem como publicar e mostrar o resultado imediatamente?

Segue o código:

**Dashboard**

```
<form name="updatePost" method="post" action="update_post.php">

    Nome: <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="status" name="data" /> </br>


    <input style="margin-left:10px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="POST" onclick="updatePost"/>
    </form>
<script>
   $("#updatePost").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       dataType:'html',
       url:"update_post.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:({+input+'did='+did+msg='+msg}),
       beforeSend: function(data){ 

         success: function(response) {
        $('#status').html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
return false;});
</script>
```

**update_post.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');
$msg =  $_POST['data'];
$sid = $_SESSION['id'];
$did = $_POST['did'];
$type = 'user';
if(!empty($msg)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(SID,DID,Message,`P/U`) VALUES ('$sid','$did','$msg','$type')";
    if($result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die('error!!'))
    { 
        echo 'OK';

        header('http://localhost/profile.php');

    }
    else{
      echo 'Error'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Existe uma div que mostra todos os status embaixo do formulário de envio:

```
<div id="posts" class="span9">
        <br><b>Recent Posts</b><br><br>
        <?php require_once('recent_posts.php');?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ta mesmo dando Refresh? Eu tentei reproduzir seu codigo mais ou menos aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Podes explicar de onde vêm estas variáveis `data:({+input+'did='+did+msg='+msg}),`? e quais são os dados que queres enviar para o servidor? (pois só vejo 1 input)

Comment: Olá, então ai que está o problema, eu sei que isto está errado, e não está enviando nada, nenhuma requisição, eu creio que os dados que tenho que enviar são esses do update_post.php

 $msg =  $_POST['data'];
 $sid = $_SESSION['id'];
 $did = $_POST['did'];
 $type = 'user';

Comment: Mas queres enviar do browser para o PHP certo? e aí é só 1 input que queres enviar?

Comment: acho que sim, eu nunca mexi com Ajax, conheço bem pouco, o que eu preciso, é enviar o post do usuario creio que seja apenas o $msg =  $_POST['data'];, por meio do input, apos clicar no botão ele deve aparecer em uma div, por meio de jquery, sem precisar dar refresh na pagina, Desculpe não poder dar maiores explicações, sou estudante, ainda aprendendo... Desde de Já Obrigado!

Comment: Restaurei a minha resposta de ontem. Acho que está lá o que precisas fazer. Lê com atenção e pergunta nos comentários da resposta ou aqui se não perceberes alguma parte. Podes usar `@sergio` ou outra pessoa para receber um mail aqui no site. Agora vou dormir mas dou uma olhada depois aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Se não queres recarregar a página ao clicar no botão muda no botão de `type="submit"` 
 para `type="button"` depois muda `onclick="updatePost"` para `id="updatePost"`, assim o teu seletor jQuery já vai funcionar para ser ativado quando o botão for clicado.

No teu `data` não sei de onde estás a ir buscar esses valores, falta JavaScript à pergunta? mas pelo que vejo deveria ser assim:

```
data:({
    data: $('#status').val()
}),
```

os outros campos não tens na pergunta mas podes usar a mesma ideia: `chave: valor`